# How is my Android App launching itself from the background over another app?

Tags: android

Background: only 4 months into coding on the Android platform, so I'm not a pro at all the advanced features.

Scenario: My android app (several years of being live in Google Play) has just recently started having a problem which QA is reporting to me: when the app is in the background, it will sometimes automatically launch over other apps (Messages, Chrome) and display the popup message it does when it does not have connection. It should be noted that the device does have a wifi connection.

Looser details include that this is only happening on phones (not tablets) and only on wifi (not cellular). I'm not convinced about that though. It has also been reported that the popup itself overlays the messages app first, then my entire app comes in behind the popup.

I realize this is a very vague question: what mechanisms do Android apps have that could exhibit this behavior?

Additional Details:

App Config:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 25
```

App Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

App Code:

Popup in question is connected to OnConnectivityChangedListener.onConnectivityChanged() (popup shown 10 seconds after lost connection via a runnable)

```
final Runnable showOfflineWarning = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!BasicNetworkManager.isConnected()) {
            showErrorDialog("Warning");
            sLastOfflineWarningTime.set(0L);
        }
    }
};
myHandler.postDelayed(showOfflineWarning, 10000);
```

showErrorDialog does spin up a custom Activity which builds it's own dialog UI. I would expect that since the app is in the background, this dialog would be created in the background, but perhaps, due to configuration or a Motorala OS querk, it is coming to the foreground.

Device:

Model: Moto Z Droid
OS: 7.0 (nougat)

Comment: Yes this is vague. At least describe what the app is doing, which SDK level is it targeting, perhaps what version of OS this is occurring on, what broadcasts/intents it is supposed to handle (android manifest) or third party libraries you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations; I will add some more details. Please feel free to advise if you know of any behaviors that would cause this to happen.

Comment: I believe I have figured out my issue; apparently starting an activity (at least via a post-delayed handler) after being put in the background is just expected to move your app to the foreground...doesn't seem like great user experience to me, but it seems to just be a known fact. So now I'm working out how to prevent my app from taking over; will post my answer back once working.